# How to read ping information using c/c++/java

Tags: file, cmd, ping

When I ping using cmd, there are many lines for example:

```
Reply from 209.85.175.138: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
```

I want to read the time. How to read it or write the information from ping to a file?

Comment: Which one? C, C++, or Java? All three at once? Or just one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the output to a file using the `>` switch.

```
ping "www.google.com" > "results.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the C and C++ tags, the obvious way would be to use `popen`:

```
FILE *pings = popen("ping www.google.com", "r");
FILE *results = fopen("results.txt", "w");
char buffer[256];

while (fgets(pings(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pings))
    fputs(buffer, results);
```

Note that `popen` is not included in standard C or C++, but is part of POSIX, and available on most other platforms as well (e.g., Windows, though under the name `_popen`).

Comment: As I understand it `popen` excutes a command. If thats correct then it should be `popen("ping \"www.google.com\"", "r");`

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Oops -- yes, I left the "ping" out of the string. Sorry 'bout that. Note that you don't really need quotes around "www.google.com" though. If you were using a URL that included spaces, you probably would need the quotes, but I believe that would break the rules for a valid URL.